# Does including 'to be' after linking verbs sounds informal?

Tags: grammar, formal-language, informal-language, linking-verbs

Here I provide the excerpt I took from *Advanced Grammar In Use*:

> Before a noun we include **to be** when the noun tells us what the
> subject is, but often leave it out when  we give our opinion of the
> person or thing in the subject. **We leave out to be in formal
> English**. Compare:
>
> - He walked into what **seemed to be** *a cave.* (*not* … what seemed a cave.) *and*
> - She **seems (to be)** *a very efﬁcient salesperson.*

If my understanding is correct, does that mean all linking verbs (excluding the exceptions or special cases as one of them stated above) with **to be** should be avoided in formal writing, or did I just misunderstand, or does it only apply with the linking verb **seem**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may omit "to be" in formal writing when giving an opinion:

> He appears happy.

However you may include it.  The effect isn't casual:

> He appears to be happy.

You don't omit "to be" in formal or informal language when stating a fact.

> He appears to be a child.

There are plenty of other contexts where "to be" is used and can't be omitted

> I want to be happy.